# Accessing Archived Articles By a Community-Licensed User

Tags: soql, community, knowledge

I have a force.com site that takes a `KnowledgeArticle` ID as a URL parameter and renders the Article. This site uses a Community Login license model.

For various reasons I would like to make this page take a `KnowledgeArticleVersion` too. It'd look up the `KnowledgeArticleId` and pass that on to the renderer. This works fine in the controller when passed a `KnowledgeArticleVersion` Id that is Published:

```
 select KnowledgeArticleId 
 from KnowledgeArticleVersion            
 where Id = :articleId 
   and PublishStatus = 'Online' 
   and Language = 'en_US' 
   and IsLatestVersion = true
```

Building on this, for historical reasons, I would like to be able to pass the VF page the ID of an *Archived* `KnowledgeArticleVersion`. I imagine I could update it by simply changing the parameters:

```
 select KnowledgeArticleId 
 from KnowledgeArticleVersion            
 where Id = :articleId 
   and PublishStatus = 'Archived' 
   and Language = 'en_US' 
   and IsLatestVersion = false
```

This query works fine in the dev console - it returns one row. But in the controller it returns zero rows using the exact same `articleId` parameter.

With some help from colleagues and others here, I looked into permisions. Even after granting Modify All in sandbox to the Community user profile, it still didn't return any records.

The only thing left is perhaps Manage Articles, which does not seem available on this Profile, perhaps due to license type. (Instructions found [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005402&type=1%22here%22) do not reflect what is available in the UI.)

So: is there a permission or licensing reason why this Community user running a Visualforce page is not able to see the record?